# What's the difference between self-type `this: T =>` and `this: T`?

Tags: scala, syntax, self-type

Between Scala (2.12.8) self-type

```scala
trait T {
   this: Any =>
}
```

and this

```scala
trait T {
   this: Any
}
```

what's the semantics difference?

In other words, what is the purpose of `this: Any` (in the second snippet)?

I expected the compiler to yell I should not declare `this` when compiling the second code snippet, but I get this warning instead:

```
Warning:(2, 9) a pure expression does nothing in statement position
multiline expressions may require enclosing parentheses
    this: Any
```

Comment: The first one is a self-type declaration (you seem to already know this). The second one is a meaningless expression in the initializer that does nothing (that's what the compiler is telling you), similar to `trait T { 42 }`. What's your question exactly?

Comment: "Why does the compiler let me declare `this` and provide a type annotation for it?" I edited the question to make it clearer.

Comment: Mostly nitpicking, but still: annotations, type ascriptions, member declarations and self-type declarations are all different things. Annotations are the compiler-readable meta-data written starting with an `@`. There are no annotations in this question.

Comment: Sorry, I didn't mean "type annotation". I think a better term would rather be type declaration? I was talking about the thing after the `:`, which I seem to not know how to spell either! hehe

Comment: I'm pretty sure that the standard type-theoretic terminology would be "type ascription" for the `: T`-part; Scala's Language Spec uses "typed expression" for the whole `e: T` expression.

Comment: Okay! So after some "type ascription" google search, I found that `this: T` in the body of a trait can be thought of as a "cast" to the type `T` of the value `this` (which, when evaluated, does nothing (assuming that `this` is of type `T`) -- like you wrote), and is indeed not a declaration of any kind. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The keyword `this` is an expression of type `T`. `T` is subtype of `Any`, because everything is subtype of `Any`. Hence you can [explicitly ascribe type](https://www.scala-lang.org/files/archive/spec/2.11/06-expressions.html#typed-expressions) `Any` to the expression `this`. It is valid to have expressions in the initializer, so you can write the expression `this: Any` in the body of `T`.

You might as well have written

```
trait T { 42: Int }
```

or

```
trait T { ((((this: T): T): T): T): Any }
```

In both cases, `42` and `this` would be just expressions with explicit type ascription that simply don't do anything. They are not declarations, and they have nothing to do with the self type.